# SELECT2 empty results

Tags: ajax, jquery-select2

I'm creating a simple select2 search box with a remote request to a php page.

I choosed to use "json" instead of "jsonp" and it seems correctly working.

The problem is that the results are white: no writes as element list.

In the image that I cannot post because "I need at least 10 reputation to post"... -.-
You could see the input box with the letter "d" and:

1. no loading icon (because the search has correctly ended)
2. no "Search" write (because the search has correctly ended)
3. the search box height is exactly for 2 results and you can select the results but the text is invisible.. you see just the blue selection..

---

The code follows:

```
function MultiAjaxAutoComplete(element, url) {
    $(element).select2({
        minimumInputLength: 1,
        ajax: {
            url: url,
            dataType: 'json',
            data: function(term, page) {

                return {
                    q: term,
                    page_limit: 10
                };
            },
            results: function(data, page) {
                return {
                    results: data
                };
            }
        },
        formatResult: formatResult,
        formatSelection: formatSelection,
        initSelection: function(element, callback) {
            var data = [];
            $(element.val().split(",")).each(function(i) {
                var item = this.split(':');
                data.push({
                    id: item[0],
                    title: item[1]
                });
            });
            //$(element).val('');
            callback(data);
        }
    });
};

function formatResult(movie) {
    return '<div>' + movie.title + '</div>';
};

function formatSelection(data) {
    return data.title;
};



MultiAjaxAutoComplete('#advertiser', '/AJAXController');
```

and the returned json data is the following

```
[{"id":"12889","title":"Donnie Darko" },
 {"id":"8",    "title":"Another title"}
]
```

PS: I got two results because, at the moment, I'm returning the json data as direct output text with "echo <<< EOF ..."

Thank you,
Mauro

Answer (score 0):

```
var data = [
  { "id":"12889", "title":"Donnie Darko" },
  { "id":"8", "title":"Another title"}
]

$(element).select2('data', data);
```